# measure the traffic throughput on mysql table

Tags: mysql

In order to split mysql database into two different databases on different hosts. I would like to know few things:

1. what is the size of the tables.
2. what is the traffic throughput to those tables.

Size of the tables can be determined easily, but how to find traffic throughput to tables.

How to identify how many data was retrieved from specific table?

Answer (score -1):

Try MONyog which has **Disk Info** tab which shows tables size
also you will come to know most accessed tables using **Real-Time** feature of MONyog.
[image]

Answer (score -2):

[mytop](http://jeremy.zawodny.com/mysql/mytop/) mytop is a console-based (non-gui) tool for monitoring the threads and overall performance of a MySQL 3.22.x, 3.23.x, and 4.x server

Comment: In the same space (and somewhat more updated) are `mtop` and `innotop`.  None of them do what the OP is asking for, however.